# PIL - how to detect characters?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have black-and-white picture which contains characters separated by some white space between. What is the best way to detect the rect (top, bottom, left and right pixels) of each letter?

Comment: Look for the columns that are completely blank and use them as separators...

Comment: tesseract can not recognise the math formulas. I want to do this by recognising each character separatly.

Comment: Have you seen OpenCV (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) ? It's more flexible when it comes to image and pattern recognition but of course a bit more complex too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL is a rather simple image manipulation package - it can load/save crop, perform basic transforms and so on - but it completely lacks "computer science" filters that are basic for OCR (those are available in the Leptonica library, used by Tesseract). If Tesseract can't recognize what you need, as you state in the comments, get ready for some really hard work reading your own OCR software.

If all you need are the bounding rectangles for each character, that would be one order of magnitude easier to do - it  might even be feasible with PIL, but again tit would be easier with Python-leptonica bindings - you can trhen use leptonica.functions.pixFindRectangleComps - the heklp for the function is:

```
pixFindRectangleComps(*args)
            ('PIX', '*pixs')       
    ('l_int32', 'dist')       
    ('l_int32', 'minw')       
    ('l_int32', 'minh')       
      pixFindRectangleComps()

          Input:  pixs (1 bpp)
                  dist (max distance allowed between bounding box and nearest
                        foreground pixel within it)
                  minw, minh (minimum size in each direction as a requirement
                              for a conforming rectangle)
          Return: boxa (of components that conform), or null on error

      Notes:
          (1) This applies the function pixConformsToRectangle() to
              each 8-c.c. in pixs, and returns a boxa containing the
              regions of all components that are conforming.
          (2) Conforming components must satisfy both the size constraint
              given by @minsize and the slop in conforming to a rectangle
              determined by @dist.
(END)
```

Where pix is the leptonica library image object, and "boxa" is a list of rectangle objects.

I had started the Python bindings for Leptonica, currently available at:http://code.google.com/p/pylepthonica/wiki/Home - I had not put much love in these bindings since, but they should work fine for leptonica 1.67 (which is +/- two years old now)